# Restart django on linux

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

Ive deployed a django app on linux using nginx, supervisor and gunicorn.

I have made updates (using GIT and manually in settings.py). The files changed but the application has not changed (i.e. it still functions the same as before the changes were added).

I've tried lots of commands but none of them work e.g.

```
//reload/restart nginx
sudo service nginx restart
sudo systemctl reload nginx
sudo systemctl restart nginx

//reload supervisor
sudo supervisorctl reload

//restart gunicorn (supervisor)
sudo supervisorctl restart gunicorn


//reboot ubuntu using systemctl
sudo systemctl reboot
//reboot ubuntu
sudo reboot now
//force reboot ubuntu
sudo reboot -f
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `ps aux | grep gunicorn` and when you have pid try `kill -9 [pid]` and then restart

Comment: Thanks for the comment - made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: Try `supervisorctl restart <program name>` . Here <program name> is your **supervisor program name** that runs your gunicorn python process. You can find the program name inside `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/<your config file for django>`